# How to increase a number by a certain amount every second smoothly?

Tags: java, android, algorithm, timer

I am trying to develop a [Cookie Clicker](http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/) kind of app called Shaking.

If you don't know what Cookie Clicker is:

Cookie Clicker is a game where you click a cookie to kind of "bake" a cookie. You try to get as many cookies as you can and you can use the cookies to buy stuff which helps you to bake cookies. For example, you can use 50 cookies to buy a cursor which automatically adds one to your cookie count every 10 seconds. Every item that you can buy has a Cps amount (Cookie per second). So the cursor is 0.1 Cps.

In my version of this game, you shake the phone instead of clicking cookies. So Cps turns into Hz!

Now what I want to do is to increase the shake count not every second, but every minimum possible amount of time. I really have not explained this very clearly, have I? For example, if the player owns something that is 100Hz, I don't want to increase the shake count by 100 every second, I want to increase it by 1 every 0.01 second! I have already written a timer class using Android's `Handler` class but that is not related.

Here is what I have tried:

I created a `TimerTuple` class to store a timer interval and the amount of shakes to increase once every that interval. So in the above example, timer interval would be 10ms and the amount to increase is 1. And btw, I am using `BigDecimal` for the Hz because it can get very big.

Here's the class, nothing special:

```
// This is an inner class. Don't tell me that I cannot use static in a class definition!
private static class TimerTuple {
    private BigDecimal shakeIncrement;
    private int timerInterval;

    public TimerTuple(BigDecimal shakeIncrement, int timerInterval) {
        this.shakeIncrement = shakeIncrement;
        this.timerInterval = timerInterval;
    }
}
```

And I write a method called `getTimerTuple` that returns a `TimerTuple`, so that I can use this information to set the timer's interval and add the correct amount to shake count.

```
private TimerTuple getTimerTuple () {
    int timerInterval = 1000;
    BigDecimal shakeIncrement = new BigDecimal(getCurrentHz ());

    if (shakeIncrement.toBigInteger ().compareTo (BigInteger.ZERO) == 0) {
        return new TimerTuple (BigDecimal.ZERO, 1);
    }

    if (shakeIncrement.compareTo (new BigDecimal (Integer.toString (timerInterval))) < 0) {
        timerInterval = timerInterval / shakeIncrement.intValue ();
        shakeIncrement = new BigDecimal ("1");
        return new TimerTuple (shakeIncrement, timerInterval);
    } else {
        shakeIncrement = shakeIncrement.divide (new BigDecimal (Integer.toString (timerInterval)), 8, RoundingMode.DOWN);
        timerInterval = 1;
        return new TimerTuple (shakeIncrement, timerInterval);
    }
}
```

I think what I am doing here is correct, but really, I'm not sure.

And every time the timer ticks, I do this:

```
TimerTuple tuple = getTimerTuple ();
if (tuple.timerInterval != timer.getInterval())
    timer.setInterval (tuple.timerInterval);
currentShakes = currentShakes.add(tuple.shakeIncrement);
// Code to display the shake amount goes here...
```

I don't know whether you can understand all this mess that I have made though.

I was not sure whether this will work or not, so I moved all of the stuff above to a normal Java application to test it as it is easier to do so. I changed the timer to `javax.swing.Timer`. Then I created a `JFrame` and put a `JLabel` in it. I used this label to display the shake count. I set the Hz to 1000 just to se what would happen. My expected result was that every second the shake count will increase by 1000. But of course, it did not work. The shake count is very slow, roughly (I did not use a real timer to measure!) 1000 shakes per 2 seconds!

I don't know how can I fix it. Does this exceed the maximum limit of refreshing the screen or something? Or is it the timer's problem? Or is my calculations wrong?

Edit:

I stepped through the code using a debugger and found that my maths are correct. I tried setting current Hz to 20000 and run the `getTimerTuple` and I get the correct result. i.e. timer interval is 1ms and shake increment is 20.

For those who don't understand what `TimerTuple` does, it basically says that "Every `timerInterval` ms, the shake count should increase by `shakeIncrement`". I can then use this information to set the `timer`'s interval to `tuple.timerInterval`.

So I still want to know how can I make the label display the correct shake count per second.

Edit:

This time it's just some additional information.

I successfully calculated how slow the shakes are incrementing. When currentHz = 1000, the actual Hz is 497. Then I tried setting currentHz to 500 and see that actual Hz is 325. I concluded that the ratio of currentHz to actual Hz is not always 2 : 1!

Then I tested some other values and plotted a graph showing how the expected Hz (curretHz) increases with actual Hz:

[image]

And I plotted another graph showing how the ratio is changing

[image]

I think that these shows that the ratio and the expected ratio is really random. This confuses me even more!

Comment: step through your program with a debugger

Comment: @keyser how does that solve the problem? Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: What is `timer` in your last snippet? I can't find a reference to it in your code.

Comment: Oh, is that the `javax.swing.Timer`?

Comment: And you say that "1000 shakes per 2 seconds" is slow. What would you expect to be a reasonable number?

Comment: 1000 per 1 second of course! Because I set the current Hz to 1000, right? @Mike

Comment: And yes, that is `javax.swing.Timer` @Mike

Comment: Honestly, I'm just having a hard time following your question. But I'm attempting to work my way through it, so any additional information is helpful; especially with regards to the context.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97736/discussion-between-sweeper-and-mike).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I know you've determined that your math is correct. However, I would suggest that you simplify your code by trying to use `BigDecimal` objects throughout (as you will see I've done with your code).

With respect to getting it displayed, I've implemented a simple `ActionListener`, attached to a `javax.swing.Timer`, and have it updating an extremely basic Swing window.

## TickerTest

```
package test;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TickerTest {
    private static final BigDecimal ONE_THOUSAND = BigDecimal.TEN.pow(3);
    private static final BigDecimal CURR_HZ = BigDecimal.TEN.pow(4).multiply(new BigDecimal(2));
    private static final JLabel label = new JLabel("<not running>");
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                TimerTuple timerTuple = getTimerTuple();
                BigDecimal ratio = timerTuple.getTimerInterval().divide(timerTuple.getShakeIncrement(), 8, RoundingMode.DOWN);
                label.setText(ratio.toString());
            }
        };
        
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, listener);
        timer.start();
    }
    
    private static TimerTuple getTimerTuple () {
        BigDecimal timerInterval = ONE_THOUSAND;
        BigDecimal shakeIncrement = getCurrentHz();

        if (shakeIncrement.equals(BigDecimal.ZERO)) {
            return new TimerTuple(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal.ONE);
        }

        if (shakeIncrement.compareTo(timerInterval) < 0) {
            timerInterval = timerInterval.divide(shakeIncrement);
            return new TimerTuple(BigDecimal.ONE, timerInterval);
        } 
        else {
            shakeIncrement = shakeIncrement.divide(timerInterval, 8, RoundingMode.DOWN);
            return new TimerTuple (shakeIncrement, BigDecimal.ONE);
        }
    }

    private static BigDecimal getCurrentHz() {
        return CURR_HZ;
    }
}
```

## TimerTuple

```
package test;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class TimerTuple {
    private BigDecimal shakeIncrement;
    private BigDecimal timerInterval;

    public TimerTuple(BigDecimal shakeIncrement, BigDecimal timerInterval) {
        this.shakeIncrement = shakeIncrement;
        this.timerInterval = timerInterval;
    }

    public BigDecimal getShakeIncrement() {
        return shakeIncrement;
    }

    public BigDecimal getTimerInterval() {
        return timerInterval;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you show the ratio of `timerInterval` and `shakeIncrement` in the label? My intention is to show the shake count.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was saying. After all the explanation, I still didn't understand what you were trying to do lol. You said you had the correct math though, so just jam that in there instead.